# IOS archive creates second file preventing distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a weird problem with archiving for distribution. One of many object files are added as top level files. Here's what I get when I try to upload:

[image: message from xcode validator]

I've searched the info.plist file, my scheme, and manually checked everything I can, including the archive itself. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your build target info and build phases?

Comment: Thanks! You gave me a couple of places to look. I had a .m file in the Copy Bundle Resources. It's all working now.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it to close the question and help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment above, I had put a .m file in the Copy Bundle Resources portion of Build Phases. Once I removed that, it worked fine.

Thanks for the tip!